# java EasyMock ignore calls to an object from TestedClass' methods

Tags: java, easymock

I have a class where I have an object. I am testing a method that calls this object, but it the object has nothing to do with my test, so I'd like to ignore it.

```
Class TestedClass {
 ObjectX obj;

  method() {
   /* some processing */
   obj.someMethod().otherMethod(lotofparameters);  /* i want to ignore this line in my test */ 
  }
}
```

So I want to test the `method()` without calling those methods on `obj` with parameters.

Thank u

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mock it using the `createMock` method. Then use the `anyTimes` method to basically ignore any calls to it.

```
expect(objMock.someMethod())
        .andReturn(42).times(3)
```

I threw in a return in case you needed it for something. Check out [their documentation](http://easymock.org/EasyMock3_0_Documentation.html) for more.

**EDIT** (to address the first comment)

Make `someMethod` return another mock. Then mock `otherObj.otherMethod`. As for the parameters, consider using the matchers listed in the documentation I linked to. You can even make your own matcher, so maybe that can help solve your issue.

Comment: Well, actually on the `obj` I call someMethod().othermethod(lotofParameters)
So I would like to omit these lotofParameters